# Adobe Illustrator: Creating a plastic/three-dimensional helix

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, gradient, research

This question is based on a question I have posted here previously: [Adobe Illustrator: Creating an helix](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/81255/adobe-illustrator-creating-an-helix)

In Illustrator, I am able to create the following tube-like shape, by creating a blend out of two circular shapes by giving them a gradient stroke:

[image: Gradient-Tube]

[image: Gradient-Tube_gifAnimation]

How can I turn a tube like this into a helix? In other words, I want the tube to follow the path of a helix.

[image: Helix-Path]

EDIT:
As one of the commenters suggested, replacing the spine of the blend with the path of the helix actually works fine, here's the result:

[image: 3D-Helix]

Comment: Edit blend replace spine... though this is not a good idea.

Comment: @joojaa Why ain't it a good idea?

Comment: Your creating a lot of redundant objects.

Comment: @joojaa And what would be a better idea to go about this?

Comment: @joojaa Replacing the spine actually works just fine for me. What did you mean by redundant objects?

Answer (score 1):

If both ends of the spiral are hidden behind other structures, then a pile of simple identical rings can be a plausible fake spiral:

[image: a pile of rings]

Used ring is 3D revolved ellipse. To get it tilted, do envelope distort. To keep tens of rings light for the computer, make one and use it as a symbol.

This job is much easier in a proper 3D program, but the created scenery is not available for Illustrator as AI shape, only as a bitmap image. In real 3D there are no difficulties with spiral's ends and viewing angles.